# Different languages via command line paramaters

Tags: qgis, command-line, internationalization

I'm looking for a way to start different qgis instances in different languages simultaneously without changing the settings in qgis.

Is it possible to define the language with a command line parameter or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible, just run QGIS from the command line in this way:

```
qgis --lang en
```

Then, from another console:

```
qgis --lang es
```

However, be aware that using QGIS in one instance might store settings in your operating system that could then eventually interfere with your other instances.